# How to copy multiple SELECTED ID from dxDatagrid?

Tags: devexpress, devextreme, dx-data-grid

I am having checkbox in dxDatagrid, I want to copy selected ID from dxDatagrid on single click and also i want in comma separated way(**I mean selected value or ID should get copied in comma separated way**). I tried multiple ways but none work for me.

I hope I made my query clear and its a very challenging question to solve for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `selectedRowKeys()` method, to get an array of selected rows.
FYI: you can also get rows data from `getSelectedRowsData()`

read more: 
https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Methods/#getSelectedRowKeys

https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Methods/#getSelectedRowsData